# Does using google map style reference or not affect the invoice?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, customization

As you know, if you do not make any customization, google map api shows a lot of information on the map such as roads, buildings, countries. I am wondering, if I do customization on google map, will it affect my bill? For example, does the following code pieces have the same effect on my bill?

```
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 zoom: 6
});
```

VS

```
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
 zoom: 6,
 styles: [{
  featureType: 'all',
  elementType: 'labels',
  stylers: [{
   visibility: 'off'
  }]
 }, {
  featureType: 'administrative',
  elementType: 'labels',
  stylers: [{
   visibility: 'on'
  }]
 }]
});
```

Comment: Based on the Google Maps [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing#dynamic-maps), Maps JavaScript API or Dynamic Maps are only billed per every instance of `google.maps.Map()` object and interactions on the map such as panning, zooming or switching layers does not generate additional charges

Comment: Thanks @jabamataro so the cost of the above 2 code snippets is equal, right ?

Comment: Yes. Correct @zahitUcman